# How to access the value of the variables of the anonymous inner class from the outer class?

Tags: java, android

For eg

Accessing a variable present in the OnClickListener from the outside class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point about anonymous classes is that you don't need to refer to them. If you do need to refer to a class it should not be anonymous.

Just because `OnClickListener`s are usually anonymous doesn't mean they have to be. You can do this instead.

```
private static final class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int field;

    private int getField() { return field; }

    // constructor and onClick() method
}
```

Then

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
view.setOnClickListener(myListener);
int a = myListener.getField();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother, either name your class or move that variable to the outside class instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky, but you have two options:

1. Create a class that can store some value, create an instance outside and put it final. At the end, modify the internal value of the class with a setter for example.
2. If your variable is too simple to create an object, create outside a final array with length 1 and inside the anonymous class assign the value of this 0 position.